# GIS / Map display component

Tags: java, eclipse, gis

For a quick demonstrator I'm looking for a SWT or Swing component which can display geographical data. Unfortunatly I'm disconnected from the internet, so Google Maps won't help.

The general idea is to assemble a small eclipse RCP application with just 'map view', connect to a custom web service, that provides geographical data (tracks) and display everything on the view. I had a *very* quick look at **uDig**, but couldn't find out so far if uDig is capable of displaying updated tracks.

Vector maps (shapes) are sufficient, I do not need rasterized map data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with OpenMap 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one should work for you, but it is not free

http://www.esri.com/getting_started/developers/java-products-tools.html

Comment: Yes, but I can't spend money this time.